# Не могу нормально записать кириллицу в .txt (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def write(*number1):
    number1 = 1
    while number1 <= number2:
        f = open('x.txt', 'a')
        f.write(str(input("ТЕСТ-->")))
        if number1 < number2 and number2 >= 2:
            f.write(str("\n"))
        number1 += 1
        if number1 == number2:
            f.close()
number2 = int(input('КОЛИЧЕСТВО СТРОК==>'))
if number2 >= 1:
    write()
```

В итоге записываются вопросительные знаки в ромбиках.
И еще одна ерунда... Когда пишу f.read() не выводит текст который в файле записан.

Comment: Пробовали `open('x.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: Чем открываете файл? Обычный блокнот windows или что-то другое? По поводу чтения - я подозреваю, что вы либо читаете данные сразу после того как записали (текущая позиция в конце файла - после конца файла ничего нет), либо открываете в режиме добавления (`'a'`) - опять же текущая позиция после открытия в таком режиме в конце файла, чтобы туда добавлять данные.

Comment: Я открывала питоном, чтобы записать текст. Проблема в том что когда я потом просматриваю, что у меня в x.txt через блокнот то там вместо кириллицы вопросительные знаки в ромбиках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `open('x.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')`
Нет смысла в конструкции `str(input())` т.к. `input()` возвращает строку.

```
def write(*number1):
    number1 = 1
    while number1 <= number2:
        f = open('x.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
        f.write(input("ТЕСТ-->"))
        if number1 < number2 and number2 >= 2:
            f.write("\n")
        number1 += 1
        if number1 == number2:
            f.close()
number2 = int(input('КОЛИЧЕСТВО СТРОК==>'))
if number2 >= 1:
    write()
```